# Finding the fundamental frequency of a speech using autocorrelation function

Tags: matlab

I don't understand why do we use the autocorrelation function to find the fundamental frequency(F0) of a speech signal. I understand that: The autocorrelation function is used to show the similarities between the signal and the lagged version of the same signal. And I got the way how to calculate the fundamental frequency(F0) using autocorrelation.But what is the relationship between autocorrelation and F0??!

Comment: it's because if $x(t)$ is periodic with period $P$, so also is the autocorrelation of $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

F0 or pitch is a human psychoacoustic phenomena, likely perceived (see psychology of music and audiology research papers) due to a certain number of lagged similarities in the audio waveform at certain distances and periods of repetitions, which, as the question stated, the auto-correlation function tends to detect or estimate (if the autocorrelation results are reasonable bounded in distance using reasonable thresholds to reject octave errors.)